# Create virtual function with unknown number of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, abstract

I am looking to have a virtual class used to ensure that all inheriting classes have the following functions

```
Initialize()
IsInitialized()
Clear()
```

Maybe there is another approach but the use of the abstract class seems to be the best options as far as I can tell.

The issue is that the Initialize() does not always have the same parameters For example:

```
class baseObject
{
    virtual void Initialize(...) = 0; //Only want to ensure Initialize is implemented in the inheriting class but parameters may very
    virtual void Clear() = 0;
    virtual bool IsInitialized() = 0;
}

class triangle : public baseObject
{
    virtual void Initialize(double length1, double length2, double length3); //Three parameters
    virtual void Clear();
    vitrual bool IsInitialized();
    ...
}

class square : public baseObject
{
    virtual void Initialize(double baseLength, double baseHeight); //two parameters
    virtual void Clear();
    virtual bool IsInitialized();
    ...
}

etc...
```

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking about it wrong? Perhaps you should make *constructors* for the initialization of each object instead? If you use constructors, all three of the listed functions simply won't be needed.

Comment: Just about Anything is possible in c++ but trying to force a square peg into a round hole is a clear sign you should rethink what you’re doing.

Comment: @Taekahn Sometimes brute force is not needed... https://youtu.be/baY3SaIhfl0 ;)

Comment: Let's say a function has returned to you a `baseObject*` that points to an object that needs to have its `Initialize` method called. How many parameters is it expecting / can it handle? (If you cannot answer without knowing which derived class was instantiated, then `Initialize` probably has no business being defined at the `baseObject` level.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Maybe I should have chosen different function names... maybe Update() instead of Initialize(). I will have one class that has a bunch of objects that will need to be updated and am looking for a way to "force" a template if you will. I like the idea of using the constructor but it does not allow for the dynamic update.

Comment: @JaMiT that is a very good point. Thanks I didnt think of it that way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude dang it. that was a great video. I hear what you are saying. Thanks for the quick response. 

It would still be interesting to know if there is a solution just out of curiosity sake but I have been convinced it is a bad architechtural decision.

Comment: @JCoder every basic c++ program does what you’re looking for in `main`.